# Undefine getlistview method in activity

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget35"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main.xml file.
Now I am trying to get the list view and for that I wrote following code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();
```

But when I am getting error that
"method getListView() is undefine for the main activity".So can you help me for this error.

Comment: Change `ListView lv = getListView();` to `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)`

Comment: thank u for your comment,I got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

**`getListView()` method is useful when you extend `ListActivity`.**

bt in other case just use below method to define ur `ListView` object.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

**E.g.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    }
}
```

if you want to use that method you have to extend `ListActivity` to your class.

**E.g.**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = getListView();
    }
}
```

Comment: @sheetal.gami then plz accept answer and vote up.. so it help other people too